# How insert increment value after point

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

On my page, I have two field

1. **CLASSID**, which **is DROP-Down** contains value 1,2,3,4,5,...
2. **ClassValue**, which **is TEXTBOX**

Here is my database record

```
[ClassValue] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
```

Here is my select query which contains some records like this

```
ClassValue
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3 ... 1.10...1.100 (Allowed)
2.0
2.1
2.2
2.4 ....2.10.. Upto 2.100 (Allowed)
```

When I run my page from the dropdown  **CLASSID** let's say I select **2** then from this column **ClassValue**, it will find how many records are there if the last record let's say **2.21**, then I want to display **2.22** in my **ClassValue** textbox and if the range reached up to **2.100** then I want to say no space available please selected another ID from the dropdown.

Can anyone suggest to me how to perform this task?

DATA TYPE [nvarchar] (5) is fixed because of my client's suggestion.